# c# msbuild execution from command line on some computersskips the signing phase WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, msbuild, code-signing

I am currently writing a Windows app that builds and signs WP8 projects. msbuild command is executed as a program inside my console application which is written in C#. I am running this command :

msbuild /p:SignXap=true /p:SignKeyFile=path\key.pfx target.csproj (password is extracted)

It executes well on my computer but on another computer it skips the signing phase. Basically everything executes as usual but just skips the signing like it wasnt defined. There are no error messages and since these outputs are produced by msbuild.exe there is nothing much that I can do.

Certificate is added to the store and app has admin privelages.

What can be different between two machines that it just skips the signing phase without complaining? Does anyone faced a similar problem or have an idea?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could cross check on the following requirements for company apps build as in the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn168929(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_msbuild

> Command-line precompilation and signing are available only for apps that target Windows Phone 8.
>   Command-line precompilation and signing for Windows Phone 8 projects require Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. The command-line properties described in this section are not included in the Windows Phone SDK 8.0.